# iOS 10, Swift 3.0, Animation not smooth

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a UITextField that should take the size of the NavigationBar and replace it like the UISearchController does. I implemented this feature using UIView.animation and it is almost all ok, but during the animation remains a small gap between the NavigationBar and my TextView control as if the collapsing of the NavigationBar is taking place a fraction of a second before moving the UITextView control to take the space released by the navigation control, and that is visible to the user because there is a thin line, like a separator, between the 2 controls until the animation is done. Then it look ok. Any idea on how to perform a more smooth animation ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Please check that the simulator does not slow down animations]
Please check that the simulator does not slow down animations

Comment: Thanks... but the video is taken from my real device. The problem is exactly the same in both the simulator and a real iPhone